# Merge Microsoft Teams channels with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to merge two Microsoft Teams channels using PowerShell?

If that is not possible what about copy posts from one channel to another?

I have found some expensive software to do so but was hoping PowerShell would do the job.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to merge? The posts? There's really much more behind it as the Team members would also have to replicated for a start and then transfer the posts that would have a unique ID and timestamp to the target channel. Using the available PowerShell module from MS I'm not sure this can be done as there is no explicit cmdlet for this. Maybe tapping into the SDK it might be possible but as you've mentioned someone found a niche to cash on.

Comment: Just to be able to merge/copy the posts, that would be good enough for me.

Comment: Quick Google search didn't yield anything promising... PowerShell is not your option here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no direct method of doing copy-paste/merge using PowerShell but you can definitely try out using Microsoft Graph API.

What you can do is

1. [Get channel messages.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) - You will get all the message from the channel you want to copy.
2. [Send chatMessage in channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

This way you will be able to get messages and post them one by one(you can write some program to do it faster) or you can also follow this ["*Import third-party platform messages to Teams using Microsoft Graph*"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams)

Thank you.